Browser App Not Always Recognizing URI Intent on Android
I have a function that checks if there is a browser app capable of executing a given action with a URI and performs that action. (This is necessary because specific actions are required if no browser settings are configured.)
fun handleExternalBrowser(uriString: String) {
    val uri = uriString.toUri()
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
    val packageManager = this.packageManager

    val canOpenUrl = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            intent, PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY.toLong()
            )
        ).isNotEmpty()
    } else {
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
        ).isNotEmpty()
    }

    if (canOpenUrl) {
        try {
            this.startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Failure log output
        }
    } else {
        // Failure log output
    }
}

I’ve also applied the following configuration in the Manifest:
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent>
</queries>

The problem is that even when there is a browser app on the phone, sometimes the action fails (but reinstalling the app makes it successful again). Can you tell me why this might be happening?
I tried executing a function that launches an external browser with a specific URI to see if it could handle the request. I expected the browser app to open and navigate to the specified URI without any issues. However, sometimes the function fails even though a browser is installed on the device. Reinstalling the my app seems to temporarily resolve the issue.
